# How do index's increase in python 2D lists?

Tags: python, list

new to python - re the below code.

I'm confused as to why the index for 7 is `[2][2]`. I expected it to be `[4][0]`, given that up until this point I had learned that indexes increased by going `[0][0]`, `[0][1]`, [1][0], etc. Any help appreciated - ty.

```
#Checkpoint 1
incoming_class = [["Kenny", "American", 9], ["Tanya", "Russian", 9], ["Madison", "Indian", 7]]

print(incoming_class)

#Checkpoint 2
incoming_class[2][2] = 8

print(incoming_class)
```

Comment: The first index is the sublist, the second index is the element within that list. You only have `[0]` through `[2]` as valid sublists. Then each of those have `[0]` to `[2]` elements within those sublists. So value `7` is at sublist `[2]` and element `[2]`.

Comment: `a = incoming_class[2]; print(a); b = a[2]; print(b)` — That should make things pretty clear…

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

```
#                     0          1        2
incoming_class = [["Kenny",   "American", 9],  # 0
                  ["Tanya",   "Russian",  9],  # 1
                  ["Madison", "Indian",   7]]  # 2
```

When we say `incoming_class[2][2]`, we mean to take

- row #2, i.e. the element with index 2 from incoming_class (`["Madison", "Indian", 7]`)

  - `incoming_class[2] == ["Madison", "Indian", 7]`
- colmn #2, i.e. the element with index 2 from what we just found (`7`).

  - `incoming_class[2][2] == 7`

Answer (score -1):

As explained in the comment by @cory-kramer you have a list of lists.

Every element of the list is indexed by the first number so `[0][x]`, `[1][x]`, and so on. Because it's a list of lists, every element of the list is actually another list, and it has a number of elements itself indexed by another index so, for the first list you have `[0][0]`, `[0][1]` and so on.

In your case the element 7 is `[2][2]`

I suggest checking how lists work in Python [here](https://blog.finxter.com/python-list-of-lists/)